# How to use regionCode Filter in Youtube Data Api 3

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying apply country filter my api request. But it not working. 
Normal request

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=viewCount&part=snippet&type=video&videoCategoryId=34&key=API_KEY&alt=json
```

With Region Code

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?regionCode=TR&order=viewCount&part=snippet&type=video&videoCategoryId=34&key=API_KEY&alt=json
```

Requests return same result

Comment: It looks right. regionCode only limits the results to videos ALLOWED in the region. Are there any videos returned that you believe are not allowed in Turkey?

Comment: @johnh10 It is return all videos.not just Turkey videos.

Comment: regionCode is not supposed to return 'just Turkey videos', but videos allowed to be seen in Turkey.

Comment: Hmm. Tank you friend. So i want filter of video languange . How i can

Comment: You can try parameter 'relevanceLanguage' (see https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) but YouTube states "Please note that results in other languages will still be returned if they are highly relevant to the search query term."

Comment: You could also try specifying a `location` and `locationRadius`, but I'm not sure how accurate your results would be after putting so many filters on it.